# Process the file before uploading it

Tags: java, javascript, upload, client-server, swfupload

I got a form with SWFUpload.
Files uploaded to the server are converted server-side (video being compressed, images being resized etc)

Question is - can i delegate some of the functionality to client-side (like image resizing), to save some bandwidth for user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Video compression via Javascript would probably slow the browser so much that it wouldn't be bandwidth savings and if anything would probably annoy the end user.

Comment: Thanks, very valid point. Though it doesn't have to be javascript compression. Maybe some process, just initiated by javascript?